# How do I use sed or awk to remove text?

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk

I have the following line in a file:

```
      Linux Release............5.4.2.0-02 12_12_2011_07:31:23
```

How do I remove all characters before the first number with sed or awk?

I wish to get the following result:

```
      5.4.2.0-02 12_12_2011_07:31:23
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -e 's/[^0-9]\+//'
```

Comment: what I need to change in the syntax in order to run it also on SOLARIS?

Comment: I don't think redirection works that way.  Try `echo " InSight Release............4.3.7.1-02.4 February-20,-2011-9:56:19" | sed 's/[^0-9]\+//'`, it works for me.

Comment: @Eytan: You want it to work on Solaris, but you tagged your question "Linux". Do you need it to work on both?

Comment: @MadHatter: Did you mean for your comment to be attached to Birei's answer? If so, the `<<<` is for a Bash here-string. Other shells may not support it.

Comment: Denis, yes, I did, and thanks for that - one learns something every day!

Answer (score 1):

One way using `sed`:

```
sed 's/^[^0-9]*//' <<<"      Linux Release............5.4.2.0-02 12_12_2011_07:31:23"
```

Result:

```
5.4.2.0-02 12_12_2011_07:31:23
```